# My fan assisted oven trips when it's pre heated

Tags: electrical, oven

My oven has been working fine since we moved in 2 years ago. I must add it was the last occupiers oven so not sure on age or how long it's been here.
    It kept tripping the electric every time it was turned on, today I changed the heating element and now it gets to a pre heated temp and then trips. Any tips would be much abliged thanks in advance.

Comment: The model# would be helpful, also is it a 40 or 50 amp breaker that is tripping?  I had a dual fuel range that had 240v and a separate 120v for the electronics that controlled the oven and convection fan. I figured it was set up this way for older 3 wire 240  (no neutral) homes.

Comment: The model is a TRICITY BENDIX.

Comment: I'm terribly with electrics I can't tell what what the breaker amp is.

Comment: When I removed the old heating element there were only 2 wires connected. There are 3 elements for wires to connect to do u think the middle wire fell off and this could be the problem

Comment: Can you post photos of the oven's nameplate and of your breaker panel?

Comment: Usually the elements themselves are only 2 wire one at each end, my example was of the supply where it plugged into the wall.